# Information required on ORDS / FOP setup of Oracle Application Express (apex.oracle.com)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apache-fop, oracle-apex-19.2, oracle-apex-20.2

**Current Scenario:**

We added a new Report Layout shared component by uploading FOP XML file in the application hosted on Oracle Application Express(apex.oracle.com) site. The PDF report generated successfully when we tried to test the layout.

**Question:**

Which FOP print server is currently being used at Oracle Application Express(apex.oracle.com) to generate PDFs?

As per Oracle Docs, Apache FOP is not available anymore in ORDS installations. So, why are report layouts based on FOP XML supported on this site? Are they using different FOP PDF generators?

Comment: Create a PDF at the site and then inside Adobe Reader, look at the properties for that PDF. It should list the PDF Producer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Kevin Brown! I was able to figure out the PDF generator, the APEX site is using BI Publisher.

[image]